# Why is "starts with vowel sound" checkbox not available?

Tags: custom-object, language, locale

I'm creating custom objects in a developer org. I see in the docs that there is a checkbox for "starts with vowel sound". However I don't see it in my org. Instead, I have a combo box asking for the gender of the object. This is curious 'cause that kind of info is relevant in Spanish, where most sustantives have a gender. But I set already the language and locale in the org to English and US values, and I still don't get the checkbox I'm looking for when creating a custom object. Right now I'm in a Spanish speaking country and it feels like location/browser language determined the presence of those language specific controls.

How can I have the "starts with vowel sound" available to select when I create custom objects?

Comment: When i changed the Default language from Spanish to English, its switched from drop down to checkbox. Please double check your org default Language by going to Company Profile -> Company Information

Comment: @VigneshwaranG Post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i changed the Default language from Spanish to English, its switched from drop down to checkbox. Please double check your org default Language by going to Company Profile -> Company Information

Answer (score 0):

If the company language is set to English, and all users are set to English, then you can remove all other languages. English is the only one, and 'Starts with vowel sound' reappears.